# How to calculate X and Y coordinate under dataLabels with we have data value is dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, svg, highcharts

How to calculate X and Y coordinate under dataLabels with we have data value is dynamic. 
Here is my JSfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ay5mbfew/

```
{
          name: 'Incorrect',
          legendColor: 'green',
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              zIndex: 3,
              y: -150,
              x: 90,
              borderWidth: 0,
              overflow: 'allow',
              style: {
                  fontSize: 60
              }
          },
          data: [{
              color: 'green',
              radius: '112%',
              innerRadius: '65%',
              y: 40
          }]
  }]
```

if value is changed then how to calculate x, y coordinates based on value, so that text appears on bars accordingly

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mohit, Maybe it is better to use a `pie` chart type, which has a built-in positioning of the `dataLabels`:  http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/njgtL94v/

Answer (score 1):

This sort of charts may be done in a simpler way. Instead of using complex paths I'm using circles with stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset.

I'm doing this without using Highcharts - you may not like this

Also I would advise to remove the roundness of the lines since it can cause confusion. In my code if you want to remove the roundness you need to remove this from CSS: `stroke-linecap: round;`

Please read the comments in my code.

```js
var SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let r = bg.getAttribute("r");//the radius of the chart

let items = [ {val:.17,color:"red"}, {val:.35,color:"hotpink"}, {val:.25,color:"gold"}, {val:.12,color:"skyblue"} ];//<--- change this

// the total length of the circle
let totalLength = bg.getTotalLength()


for(let i = items.length-1; i >=0 ; i--){
//the previous item in the array
  let prev = getPrev(i);
  // for every item in the items array calculate the value for the stroke-dasharray, stroke-dashoffset
  let o = {
  r:r,
  "stroke-dasharray":totalLength,
  "stroke-dashoffset": totalLength, 
  "style":  `--sdo:${totalLength * (1 - items[i].val)}`,
  stroke:items[i].color,
  transform: `rotate(${prev * 360})`,
  class:"animatable"
}
//draw the circles
drawSVGelmt(o,"circle", circles)
 // calculate the position for the text
 // first get the angle in the middle
 let textAngle = 2*Math.PI * (prev + items[i].val/2);
 // get the position and rotate the text 
 let t = {}
   t.x=r*Math.cos(textAngle);
   t.y=r*Math.sin(textAngle);
   t.transform= `rotate(${90},${t.x},${t.y})`

 //draw the text
 let _text = drawSVGelmt(t,"text", text);
 // add the text content
 _text.textContent = `${items[i].val * 100}%`;   
}


// a function to draw an svg element
function drawSVGelmt(o,tag, parent) {
  var elmt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, tag);
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      elmt.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(elmt);
  return elmt;
}

// a function to get the previous item in the array
function getPrev(i){
  let prev = 0;
  if(i > 0){
     for(let j = 0; j < i; j++){
       prev += items[j].val
     }
  } 
  return prev;
}
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 60;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

circle.animatable {
  animation: dash 0.5s ease-in forwards;
}
text {
  fill: black;
  stroke: white;
  paint-order: stroke;
  stroke-width: 5;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-anchor: middle;
  dominant-baseline: middle;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: var(--sdo);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="400" viewBox="-200 -200 400 400">
  
  <circle id="bg" r="150" stroke="#d9d9d9" />
  <g id="circles"></g>
  
  <g id="text"></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Excellent, helpful answer

Comment: maybe this line of code is superfluous - `<svg width="0" height="0"></svg>`?

Comment: Thank you @ Alexandr_TT. I've deleted that line.